# Bash Scripting: automate command in console

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am connecting to a VPN via a simple bash script, that I would like to run on computer startup, thus, I need it to be fully automated. However, the script will run "openconnect --jupiper" and ask for my credentials afterwards (about 3-4 seconds later when it acquires a connection).

Id like to have it output my credentials after some text is found (fastest and more precise way) or after a set delay (dumb and less precise way).

Is there a way to output commands after a set delay or after some text (regex match for example) is returned?

Comment: http://selvakumar.me/auto-login-openvpn-without-prompt-for-username-password-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Openconnect for example allows for setting the credentials via single line command, as such, it might have been a poor example. However not all applications support this, as such, the question still applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To automate commands, I have used over the years [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). It is great to simulate an interactive session, either when dealing with stubborn commands that do require interactivity, or to interact with active devices or other servers on your network. I still use it to login to active equipment, and fetch some statistics and perform automatic backups.

> Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs
>   according to a script. Following the script, Expect knows what can be
>   expected from a program and what the correct response should be. An
>   interpreted language provides branching and high-level control
>   structures to direct the dialogue. In addition, the user can take
>   control and interact directly when desired, afterward returning
>   control to the script.

[Using Expect Scripts to Automate Tasks](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts)

As an example, a expect script I wrote to test the POP service:

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec expect "$0" ${1+"$@"}

set force_conservative 0  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
                          ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
        set send_slow {1 .1}
        proc send {ignore arg} {
                sleep .1
                exp_send -s -- $arg
        }
}

set timeout -1
spawn telnet 127.0.0.1 110
match_max 100000
expect {
"Hello"    { send -- "USER user@domain.pt\r"; exp_continue
       }
"assword" { send -- "PASS password\r" ; exp_continue
       }
"logged"   {
         send -- "LIST 1\r" ; exp_continue
   }
-re "failed|denied"   { exit
       }
"OK 1" { send -- "QUIT\r"; }
}
```

As per my conversation bellow with @cas, I would also point out, that the simple regexp expect language subset is useful for short automations scripts/[very] rough prototypes, together with bash.

If there is a need to more convoluted handling of output, the interactive handling can/better be done with another programming language.

For instance, in python, [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/), or even in C, using [libexpect](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libexpect) or [miniexpect](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/miniexpect-a-small-expect-library-for-c/).

Lately with the devops movement, you also have got a whole host of new [and old] frameworks to automate system tasks such as [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com), Puppet, Salt.

They do require however a learning curve, and more resources. I personally favor Ansible.

[Ansible Tip: Running Interactive Scripts with Ansible](https://www.tenfourty.com/2015/05/31/ansible-tip-running-interactive-scripts-with-ansible/)

Comment: There are also `expect`-like modules/libraries for `perl`, `python`, and many other languages.  IMO it's usually better to use one of these because `expect` itself is a single-purpose language that isn't worth investing much time to lean while `perl`, `python` and others are general purpose languages that are worth the time to learn.  To start researching this, search for `Expect.pm` (or `Net::Telnet`, `Net::SSH` and many others) for `perl` or `pexpect` for `python`.

Comment: It is simple enough to script some simple jobs in a few minutes; I also never invested much time on it for similar reasons. If needing to do more convulted things with the output or input, it is indeed worth using some language. I used C to extract data customer usage and ptovisioning stats in a cable provider environment

Comment: yep, i've used expect many times myself....but it's not something i'd recommend for others to learn.  If you don't already know expect and you're going to spend some time learning a programming/scripting language, it's better to learn a good general-purpose one.

Comment: Expect is much like bash or other tools. Good for one shot a-couple of minutes scripts, and for prototyping. Expect for networking guys like me is a life safer for a quick tinkering with 2000 thousand cisco routers ;)

Comment: I am updating the answer to the tune of this conversation. Nevertheless the question asks for how to do it via scripting/bash and in that case, it is really expect the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I actually could not get "openconnect" to work correctly with all the command line arguments, so I ended up making a Expect script for it.

Rui F Ribeiro's answer was exactly on the money, however, I needed a little more research to get everything working, minor stuff, variables and such.

In the interest of who ever views this question here, I am posting the script that resolves my use-case for the original question, not because its an alternative but because it is an "extension" to Rui F Ribeiro's knowledge share.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set vpn_url "vpn.domain.com"
set vpn_username "theuser"
set vpn_password "thepassword"
set ubuntu_username "theubuntuloginuser"
set ubuntu_password "theubuntuloginpass"

set force_conservative 0  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
        ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
  set send_slow {1 .1}
  proc send {ignore arg} {
    sleep .1
    exp_send -s -- $arg
  }
}

set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
send -- "sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\"/usr/local/lib\" openconnect --juniper --no-cert-check $vpn_url -u $vpn_username\r"
expect {
  "password for $ubuntu_username:" {
    send -- "$ubuntu_password\r"
  }
}
expect -exact "password:"
send -- "$vpn_password\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: excellent news. mind you I gave a crude example for the sake of clarity. You can pass arguments, and often the string matching does not have to be exact, for instance I use assword, and it is not a typo. not dealing full string matching can be useful when dealing with slow devices or devices with configurable prompts.